# LibGDX isDirectory() returns false even though it is a directory

Tags: java, file-io, libgdx

I am currently trying to get a list of files in a directory.
When I try to get the filehandle for the directory it says that it is a file, but it isn't. When I then `readString()` from it, it returns the filenames of the files in it. This only happens in the IDE (Eclipse NEON.2), but when I export to JAR it crashes when I try to run.

How can I get LibGDX to recognise it as a directory and get all files in that directory. One last thing I have seen many anwers saying that `list()` doesn't work on desktop, but I have also read that it works. Can someone check if this is true or not.

```
public void loadEnemyBaseTypes(){
    ArrayList<FileHandle> enemyBaseFiles = new ArrayList<FileHandle>();
    FileHandle enemyBaseDirectory = 
        Gdx.files.internal("prototypes/enemybases");

    System.out.println(enemyBaseDirectory.exists());
    System.out.println(enemyBaseDirectory.isDirectory());

    String[] fileNames = enemyBaseDirectory.readString().split("\n");   

    for(int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) 
        System.out.println(fileNames[i]);   
}
```

**IDE Output**:

> true
>   false
>   base_0.enybse
>   base_1.enybse
>   base_2.enybse
>   base_3.enybse
>   base_4.enybse
>   base_5.enybse

**Terminal Output**:

> true
>   false
>   Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
>   at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
>   at java.io.Reader.read(Unknown Source)
>   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readString(FileHandle.java:207)
>   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readString(FileHandle.java:191)
>   at dev.thomaslienbacher.simplegame.controllers.EnemyManager.loadEnemyBaseTypes(EnemyManager.java:53)
>   at dev.thomaslienbacher.simplegame.controllers.EnemyManager.loadAssets(EnemyManager.java:33)
>   at dev.thomaslienbacher.simplegame.scene.GameScene.loadAssets(GameScene.java:62)
>   at dev.thomaslienbacher.simplegame.Game.update(Game.java:149)
>   at dev.thomaslienbacher.simplegame.Game.render(Game.java:134)
>   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:223)
>   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)

Answer (score 0):

I created nested folder inside Assets `list -> enemy` then I keep three `.png` files inside enemy folder having name `1.png`, `2.png` and `3.png`.

```
FileHandle enemyBaseDirectory = Gdx.files.internal("list/enemy");

System.out.println(enemyBaseDirectory.exists());
System.out.println(enemyBaseDirectory.isDirectory());

FileHandle allList[]=enemyBaseDirectory.list();

for (FileHandle fileHandle:allList)
    System.out.println(fileHandle);
```

Output on IDE `Run` tab :

> true
>  true
>  list/enemy/1.png
>  list/enemy/2.png
>  list/enemy/3.png

There is no any output on IDE local `Terminal`. My IDE is `Intellij IDEA`, hopefully result should be same on other IDE.

That is my expected output.

FileHandle's `readString()` reads the entire file into a string using the platform's default charset and if file handle represents a directory, doesn't exist, or could not be read then throw `GdxRuntimeException`.

Comment: What platform are you running on? For me on Windows, `list()` on an Internal FileHandle returns an empty array, as expected based on the Javadocs for the method.

Comment: I tried Windows and Mac both with Intellij IDEA, It give me a non zero length array. According to doc it should be a zero length array, so I tried  Eclipse Neon.3 then I got zero length array. Why some IDE give me non zero length array ?